Illegal symbol arm, ccs
I am trying to run code below:
    .global vector1, vector2   ; Declare vector1 and vector2 as global variables
    .data
vector1: .byte 10, 20, 30      ; Vector 1 with 3 elements
vector2: .byte 1, 0, 2         ; Vector 2 with 3 elements

    .text
    .global mainAsm            ; Declare mainAsm as a global function

mainAsm:
    bl dotProduct              ; Call dotProduct function
    bx lr                      ; Return from mainAsm

dotProduct:
    ldr r4, =vector1           ; Load the address of vector1 into r4
    ldr r5, =vector2           ; Load the address of vector2 into r5
    ...

ccs produces error at these two lines ldr r4, =vector1...
[E0001] Illegal symbol  modularProg.asm /gettingStarted line 12 C/C++ Problem
can anyone point what could problem be?
general.img

Does it work with other symbol? Maybe your assembler does not support the = syntax? Or maybe vector1 is a reserved word?

Yes it does work with other words, then assembler could be the problem.

I used adr r4, vector1. For now it works

assembly is specific to the assembler not the target.  No reason to assume the =label syntax is supported across all arm assembly languages. (of which there are many)

I seem to remember the =symbol syntax is supported differently across different assembly languages that support it (some will try to do an immediate instead of pc indirect, some will always do pc indirect)
